# if any div has Class through alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i have this jQuery function that checks if a particular div has the "red" class attached to it. However i want to know how i can make it so that it checks mutliple Divs not just the "#Drop1" div.

I have 4 Divs in total from #Drop1 all the way to #Drop4.

I want to get it working so that it checks all 4 Divs for the class "red" and if any div has this class show the alert message.

I've looked around and can't seem to find a concrete answer.

```
$("Button").click(function(){
    if ( $("#Drop1").hasClass("red") ) {

        alert("one of your Divs has the class red");
    }
});
```

Comment: All those elements should have a common class. Then you simply check whether class A also has class B. Doing jQuery and CSS on multiple elements by ID is usually bad practice.

Comment: Totally agree with @isherwood, your code is not reusable giving everything an id

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since each of the element's `id` attributes start with 'Drop', you could use the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) `[id^='Drop']`:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    if ($("[id^='Drop']").hasClass("red")) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Or you could just combine the attribtue selector with a class selector and check the `.length` property:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    if ($("[id^='Drop'].red").length) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: jquery docs disagree: `Description: Determine whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given class.`

Comment: @Josh Sorry for confusion, your original code would also work.

Answer (score 1):

Is there some reason why directly selecting on the class: `$( "div.red" ).each(...)` isn't going to work?